# Ruby on Rails No route matches [POST]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm attempting to maintain some legacy code but I'm struggling to figure out why my defined route isn't working.

The error I'm getting is

```
Started POST "/api/transactions/weight" ...
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/api/transactions/weight"):
```

My (simplified) route is as follows

```
namespace :api do
    resources :transactions, only: [:create] do
        post "weight", to: "transactions#weight"
    end
end
```

I've also tried moving the route outside the `resource :transactions` definition like so

```
namespace :api do
    resources :transactions, only: [:create]

    post "transactions/weight", to: "transactions#weight"
end
```

But I'm getting the same error. Am I misunderstanding route definition, or is the problem elsewhere? Thanks

Comment: The issue is not with your routes. When you have nested routes like this you need to pass in the transaction_id

Answer (score 0):

Always check `bundle exec rake routes` to understand your routes.

The `post` method defines "/weight" route as a member route (acting on a specific "transactions" resource

```
# bundle exec rake routes

api_transaction_weight POST   /api/transactions/:transaction_id/weight(.:format). api/transactions#weight
```

By default, if you don't specify `on:` option, the route inside `resources` block gets created as member route.

You want to specify it as a collection route [1] via `on: :collection`

```
namespace :api do
  resources :transactions, only: [:create] do
    post "weight", to: "transactions#weight", on: :collection
  end
end
```

```
# bundle exec rake routes

weight_api_transactions POST   /api/transactions/weight(.:format)  api/transactions#weight
```

[1] https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-collection-routes

Answer (score 0):

The way you defined routes will consider "weight" as the member route. If you want to define it as collection route.

```
namespace :api do
    resources :transactions, only: [:create] do
        collection {post :weight}
    end
end
```

The above convention will expose weight as collection route and not member route.If you want to be defined as member post request. Then use following convention

```
namespace :api do
    resources :transactions, only: [:create] do
        member {post :weight}
    end
end
```

If you are using api.rb as draw file in routes, then you need to restart your application to reflect changes in routes file.